# Spark-Cassandra Connector throws InvalidQueryException

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am facing this error :

Stack Trace:

```
16/09/22 12:35:01 ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@58aafaf
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Key length of 105500 is longer than maximum of 65535
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:184)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:798)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:617)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1005)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:928)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:823)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:255)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/09/22 12:35:01 ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@3bdd2570
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Key length of 108452 is longer than maximum of 65535
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:184)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:798)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:617)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1005)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:928)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:823)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:255)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

While trying to save a large string into the cassandra !
Could anyone please help me out in figuring this :

What is causing this error and how can I remove it , My use case is to save a very Large String in cassandra!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit on the size of the key (partition key) in the CQL that you can check at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html

The column in which you are trying to store string must be your partition key and it is crossing the limit.

you should change your table structure and remove that column for partition key and clustering key

May this will help